# How to prevent the display of image placeholder if the image is not found?

Tags: javascript, html, image, placeholder

Is there a way to not display the image placeholder if the image was not found? I've got images loaded by automatic feed, and for some items images are there, but for some there are not. So, if the image is not there, I would like to display a custom placeholder.

Comment: This really depends on how you're loading images via Javascript.  For example, if you're using JSON data coming back from the server, you could just check to see if the image url is blank and set it to another 'known' (default) url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer [here](http://www.tech-evangelist.com/2007/09/15/missing-image-fix/)

This piece of code works great!

```
function onImgErrorSmall(source)
{
source.src = "/images/no-image-100px.gif";
// disable onerror to prevent endless loop
source.onerror = "";
return true;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
<img src="/images/19013_small.jpg" alt="" onerror="onImgErrorSmall(this)" />
```

Comment: Or you could just do a $(source).remove() to avoid additional http request for this other image

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   var tester=new Image()
   tester.onload=function() {createPlaceHolderForImage(); }
   tester.onerror=function() {handleError(); }
   tester.src="http://www.temp.com/image.jpg"
```

onload function gets called if the image exists, otherwise handleError is called

Comment: Not sure which form the feed that you're using is in, but just ensure that the error event is attached to the images BEFORE they attempt to load. If the integration is done on the backend, you may need to have the src URL in an attribute other than 'src'. Then, via JS you can attach the error event and then plug the src url into the src attribute. Good luck! :)

Comment: this is just sample code to demonstrate how could this be  solved. i'm not saying it's the best way :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample using jQuery, this could also be done in JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").each(function(){
        var imgObj = $(this);
        var img = new Image();
        img.onerror=function(){ imgObj.attr('src','placeholder.gif'); }
        img.src = imgObj.attr('src');
    });
});
</script>
<ul>
<li><img src="blah.gif" /></li>
<li><img src="blah.png" /></li>
<li><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo2w.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

This code will go through each image and check if it exists.  If it doesn't exist then it is replaced with the 'placeholder.gif' image.

Comment: I seem to be having issues editing the post currently, but you can see a working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7EbP/

Comment: Well That works great. Thank you.  I am not allowed to use jQuery though.