# Show placeholder if image not found

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I was trying to use `onerror`. Whenever image is not found in the folder it displays a placeholder. My image path is dynamic and comes from backend. Below is how I used it.

```
<img class="" src="{{imagePath}}my_image.jpg" onerror="this.src='{{imagePath}}placeholder.jpg';" alt="Image not found">
```

But this is not working and giving error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript don't display the image placeholder if the image is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962912/javascript-dont-display-the-image-placeholder-if-the-image-is-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

For this I used to use `picture` tag, browsers will try first source, then second, if browser don't have picture interpreter will use `img` tag.

Like this:

```
<picture>
  <source alt="Special Days" srcset="[First Image route].jpg" type="image/jpeg">
  <source alt="Special Days" srcset="[Second Image route].jpg" type="image/jpeg">
  <img alt="Imagen" src="[First Image route].jpg">
</picture>
```